# Deleting [cssClass] from <ngx-intl-tel-input> should not make changes on the styles

Tags: angular

If I delete `[cssClass]="'custom'"`, the styles on the field changes but I have no '`.custom`' class on my .css file, and if I try to add a `.custom` class in may .css file I can't change the styles anyways. Here my code

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input
     [cssClass]="'custom'"
     [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
     [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
     [enablePlaceholder]="true"
     [searchCountryFlag]="true"
     [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2,SearchCountryField.Name]"
     [selectFirstCountry]="false"
     [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.UnitedStates"
     [maxLength]="15"
     [phoneValidation]="true"
     [separateDialCode]="false"
     [numberFormat]="PhoneNumberFormat.International"
     [inputId]="'phoneNumber'"
     [enablePlaceholder]="true"
     [customPlaceholder]="'Phone Number'"
     formControlName="phoneNumber">
</ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

With `[cssClass] = "'custom'"`
[image: Here's the field with cssClass = 'custom']

Without `[cssClass] = "'custom'"`
[image: Here's the fiel without cssClass = 'custom']

I want to know why do I see changes on the field when I delete the attribute `[cssClass]` and how can I actually make changes on the styles for this component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap:why intlTelinput changes the width of the input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418593/bootstrapwhy-intltelinput-changes-the-width-of-the-input-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try writing `.custom` class in your project level .css file i.e. `styles.css`. Which exists inside the `app` folder.

If you are writing it inside your component's css file then the style may not change. But writing in `styles.css` will change the style.

Hope it helps.